# infinitive clause

Tags: infinitive-clauses, to-infinitive

> Assess whether **the people to be protected** support the intervention.

if we say **" the people to protect**" ,  would "**the people**" still maintain the role of being passive as in the original sentence?

Comment: No, you need to use *be + past participle*. If you leave it as you say, it becomes into a *infinitive of purpose* http://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose.

Comment: @Subjunctive - If you remove the *be* then it isn't a passive, but you're quite right!

Comment: It's just called  passive infinitive: to protect (to-infinitive) versus to be protected (passive infinitive)

Answer (score 1):

The distinction lies between the *active* or *passive infinitive.*

If we choose the active infinitive form, it means that we focus about the agent who will do the action.
By choosing the passive infinitive form, we're focusing about the action.

However, after the verb *be*, the passive infinitive is normally prefered.

> » *This car is **to be washed**.* (<s>*This car is to wash.*</s>)
>   »  *The documents are **to be placed** in the box.* (<s>*The documents are to place in the box*.</s>)
>   » *The carnival is **to be celebrated** tomorrow*. (<s>*The carnival is to celebrate tomorrow.*</s>)

Both forms are possible in most cases depending of the focus:

> » *The people **to treat** / **to be treated** are in the following room.*